# Should i use 'strip_tags() ' before inserting into database or before printing on page?

Tags: php, security

I am following various steps to prevent any kind of injections or attacks on my web application. While I was following them a question came to my head:
One of the very basic actions to take to prevent attacks on your web app is to prevent the user from writing malicious scripts that could possibly hurt the other users. In the sources I've read it said that you should use `strip_tags()` or `htmlentities()` but it wasn't clear enough if I should put it before I am inserting the user data into the database or before I am printing it out or maybe both..

So basically my question is when do I use these functions?
And also what if I want to keep some of the html tags?{In case I am using a html text editor} and is it recommended at all?

Comment: This is a rather broad question. The answer would be: Don't allow anything that can be a security risk or what is not needed. First thing I do in a script that accepts user input is: [filter_input()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php). Yes, it can do tag stripping too. So, always get rid of junk as soon as computationally possible.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Hay, thanks for your comment. It's the first time i ran into filter_input() so i definetley will read about it. The last thing i want is to expose my user to potential threats. I got alot of work!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`strip_tags()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) is used to sanitize the data you receive from the users. It will try to remove all NULL bytes, HTML and PHP tags. Personally I am not a fan of this function as there are better ways to validate and sanitize input, e.g [filter-input](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php).
If you would like to keep some HTML you could take a look at http://htmlpurifier.org/

[`htmlentities()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) is used to output data into HTML context. If you are displaying anything in HTML (doesn't matter where the data comes from) you should use this to prevent XSS. [More information](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/06/preventing-xss-vulnerabilities-in-php-everything-you-need-know)

To prevent SQL injections you should use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). If you make sure to never mix data and SQL you can insert any data you would like to DB, even other SQL.

They all have different uses and prevent different kind of bugs.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. Your answer is very detailed and helped me alot. filter_input() is new to me so i am going to read about it, also the html purifier library looks like it will fit my needs perfectly so i am planning on going deeper in that to. And i definitely will use htmlentities() when displaying HTML. Already wrote a note earlier today to use prepared statements and also to move from MySQLi to PDO as it seems that most of the developers will use that because it's a standard now. You have no idea how much you helped me with your answer i am realy thankful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**strip_tags()** is used as a security measure to prevent XSS (Cross Site Scripting) attacks.

You should use it when you're recieving data to process on your site.
Generally you could use it when you handle POST and GET variables from site to site.

e.g.

If you have a login form on a *login.php* site, you will handle the POST or GET action of that form on a different (or the same) site.

Inside those POST or GET variables there could be XSS attacks like:

`<script>alert('Hi. This is a cyberattack');</script>`

What you want to do with **strip_tags()** is to remove the unwanted tags from those variables.

You could allow wanted tags inside a custom function, but that's up to you.

Comment: Hay, thanks for your answer. Inserting javascript into my database i guess wont really harm anything, but taking it out of the database and printing it on a page is where the problem at. So mabey just stripping the tags before showing the data on the page is enough?

Comment: You could say so, but I would still do it as soon as you get the data, just to be sure. You could also add some SQL Injection protection at the same time, like string escaping... Then you could add security measures inside this function or method of yours very easily, making your website more and more secure, knowing you'll have to modify only that piece of code each time.

Comment: Sometimes when i am writing a code i dont think about how complicated it is for no reason and then when i have to make some changes and edit that code i pay for not thinking about simplfying the code. It definitely will be much more efficient to use strip_tags() and other possible security measures before inserting into the database. Thanks again!